# Tortoise SVN : export differences between two tags

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there a possibility in Tortoise SVN to export only the differences between two tags or a tag and the trunk?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in the repo browser you could select the two tags within the right side of the window and with a right-mouse-click you could choose from the context menu "show differences as unified diff". You could save this diff from the editor.